# Issues to use Webhook for Microsoft Graph API

Tags: graph

I used Graph API to add web hook for group conversations. Because I need to monitor conversations for all groups, I read the group list and add web hook for every group.

After 20-30 groups (The number will change for different accounts), Graph API begins return error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "Server could not process subscription creation payload.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "af7d109a-fb6c-4b41-9aa1-988fc21309ad",
      "date": "2016-09-28T03:06:11"
    }
  }
}
```

It seems that Graph API will block after receive too many subscription request, is this right?
Then is there a way for me to monitor conversations for all group?

Comment: It would be nice if these limitations were published somewhere and we didn't have to guess

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to accomplish this except to cycle through all the users and request conversation information one at a time.  The drawback here is that it's generally a bad idea to request new information before an old request is finished (Microsoft will throttle your connection) so that limits you to about 2-3 requests/second at best.  Depending on the size you're looking at, it may be several minutes between user refreshes.

This is based on my personal experience.  I can't find any documentation that supports/denies this.